# ONGR Elasticsearch Bundle AWS Connection Issue

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, ongr

Hello Ther i try to connenct to ES indet that is located on AWS, but i still get he Error.
`[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]

  You have requested a non-existent service "es.managers.default".`

I installed the bundle using Conposer, as described on the Docs.
then added a config part tom my config.ylm

```
ongr_elasticsearch:
managers:
    default:
        index:
            index_name: contents
            hosts:
                - https://search-***.es.amazonaws.com:443
            mappings:
                - StatElasticBundle
```

---

i have a awsaccesskey and a awssecretkey, but i don't now where i have to put them, so i created a aws_connection section in the parameters.yml and try to load it

Then i try to establish a connection in my SymfonyBundle and created a class in my Bundle->DepandencyInjection folder to extend my bundle, this is where i get the error. Mayby someone of you struggled with the same error? 
Thanks for help.

```
Class StatElasticExtension extends Extension
{
    const YAML_FILES = [
        'parameters.yml',
        'config.yml',
        'services.yml'
    ];

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        foreach (self::YAML_FILES as $yml) {
            $loader->load($yml);
        }

        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $serviceDefinition = $container->getDefinition('es.managers.default');
        $awsConnections = $container->getParameter('aws_connections');
        $elasticsearchClient = $this->getClient($awsConnections);
        $serviceDefinition->replaceArgument(2, $elasticsearchClient);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct service name is `es.manager.default`.